# How can I make this regex relative URL extraction work in grep?

Tags: regex, grep

Have this string in a file and want to just extract the relative link:

```
<a href="/FreeCAD/FreeCAD-Bundle/releases/download/weekly-builds/FreeCAD_weekly-builds-28909-2022-05-20-conda-Linux-x86_64-py39.AppImage" rel="nofollow" data-skip-pjax>
```

This works in https://regexr.com/6m4vg :

```
/FreeCAD/[^]*AppImage
```

But returns nothing in grep.

```
grep -E '/FreeCAD/\[^]*AppImage' somefile
```

How can I make it work? Thanks.

Edit: source file:

```
wget https://github.com/FreeCAD/FreeCAD-Bundle/releases/tag/weekly-builds
```

Desired output:

```
/FreeCAD/FreeCAD-Bundle/releases/download/weekly-builds/FreeCAD_weekly-builds-28909-2022-05-20-conda-Linux-x86_64-py39.AppImage
```

Comment: I think this will also work: `grep -o "/FreeCAD.*AppImage" somefile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `[^"]*` instead of `[^]*`:

```sh
grep -o '/FreeCAD/[^"]*AppImage' somefile
```

`/FreeCAD/[^]*AppImage` works online because you test the pattern against the ECMAScript engine, but `grep -E` uses a POSIX ERE regex flavor, where the negated bracket expression should not be empty.

`[^]` in an ECMAScript regex flavor matches any char, so here, since `grep` works on a line by line basis, you can replace it with `.*`.

However, since the text you want to match cannot contain `"`, you can also use a more appropriate `[^"]*` pattern that matches zero or more chars other than a `"` char.